# When populating a MPMusicPlayerController with an MPMediaPlaylist, how to advance to next item, and begin playback there?

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

Here's what I'm doing:

```
self.iPodController = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
MPMediaPlaylist* playlist = [self lookupSavedPlaylist];
[self.iPodController setQueueWithItemCollection:playlist];

[self.iPodController skipToNextItem];
[self.iPodController play];
```

This results in the first song playing, not the second. This *kind of* makes sense, but it's annoying and I'm hoping there's a work-around.

Comment: Depends. What's `[self lookupSavedPlaylist]` like?

Comment: Well, it will be a playlist that was selected by the user in the past, and the persistent id was used to look it up again. It will be a valid, non-empty playlist of audio files. Why does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it turns out that if you explicitly set the `nowPlayingItem`, you won't have this issue. Here's the modified code:

```
self.iPodController = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
MPMediaPlaylist* playlist = [self lookupSavedPlaylist];
[self.iPodController setQueueWithItemCollection:playlist];
self.iPodController.nowPlayingItem = [playlist.items objectAtIndex:0]; // explicitly set to track 1 to start

[self.iPodController skipToNextItem]; // will now skip to track 2!
[self.iPodController play]; // will now play track 2
```